How to manage vanishing gradients for recursive matrix operations
I am building a neural network in PyTorch with an inner loop which applies a series of matrix operations recursively to a BxNxN matrix.
Below is a minimum working example demonstrating this inner loop, and the mean gradient as a function of the number of recursions applied:
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as f
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Normalise(matrix):
    l1_norm = torch.sum(torch.abs(matrix), axis=-2, keepdim=True)
    epsilon = torch.finfo(matrix.dtype).eps
    l1_norm = l1_norm + epsilon
    norm = matrix / l1_norm
    return norm

def NormAndSquare(matrix):
    norm = Normalise(matrix)
    mp = torch.pow(norm, 2)
    return mp

 B, N = 1, 10

 logits = torch.randn(B, N, N, requires_grad=True)
 y = torch.eye(N).unsqueeze(0).repeat(B, 1, 1)

 # Initialize y_hat
 y_hat = f.softmax(logits, dim=1)

 mean_gradients = []
 for i in range(13):
    # Zero the gradients
    if logits.grad is not None:
       logits.grad.zero_()

     # Apply NormAndSquare
     y_hat = NormAndSquare(y_hat)

     # Compute loss
     loss = f.mse_loss(y, y_hat)

     # Backward pass
     loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

     mean_gradients.append(torch.abs(logits.grad).mean().detach().item())

 plt.figure()
 plt.plot(np.arange(13), mean_gradients)
 plt.yscale("log")
 plt.ylim([1e-16, 0.1])
 plt.grid(which="both")
 plt.ylabel("Mean Gradient")
 plt.xlabel("Iteration")
 plt.show()


In this example, after around iteration 6, the mean gradient of logits rapidly vanishes, which is a problem.
What methods exist to handle this sort of situation? Are there ways I can keep an optimizer updated within an internal loop to avoid this effect?
